# json response is not the same as the sample parameter given in laravel

Tags: arrays, json, laravel

I'm working on a project with vendor company, where they provide an API and I have to post the value to their API. My code works well but I've found out that one of my JSON parameters is not the same as their given sample parameters. This is my "option" parameter, which I try to post it using postman before but got an error (Fail result):

```
"options":[{"name":"city","value":["1","200"]},{"name":"fs3","value":["1"]},{"name":"fs4","value":["2"]}]
```

and this is their sample:

```
"options": "[{'name':'city', 'value': '2'}, {'name':'fs3', 'value': '3'}, {'name':'fs4', 'value': '2'}]"
```

This is what am I doing in my controller to get the json result:

```
      $loc = $request->location;
      $price = $request->price;
      $type = $request->type;
      //$i = 0;
      if ($loc == true && $price == true && $type == true) {
         $loc_opt = [
           'name' => 'city',
           'value' => $loc
         ];

         $price_opt = [
           'name' => 'fs3',
           'value' => $price
         ];

         $type_opt = [
           'name' => 'fs4',
           'value' => $type
         ];
      }
      $all_opt = [$loc_opt,$price_opt,$type_opt];

      $data = [
        'orgname'=>"expo",
        'username'=>'expoapileadcreation@propertyguru.com.sg',
        'password'=>'926db4ec868b7a099952c1f36daf8f3cdef83164f7556b30919ab3ad720845ab',
        'sourceid'=>'1001',
        'projectid'=>'1',
        'buyeremail'=>$request->email,
        'recipientEmail'=>'expo@smartleadtrack.com',
        'buyername'=>$request->name,
        'buyerphone'=>$request->phone,
        'option'=>$all_opt
      ];
      return $data;
```

I wonder if data type in the database will affect the result but FYI the requested value is using VARCHAR data type. This is my first time working with API so I wonder if there is something I missed?

Comment: `"option"` is not the same as `"options"`

Comment: have tried `'option' => json_encode($all_opt)`

Comment: yes, but the result is like this "option": "[{\"name\":\"city\",\"value\":[\"1\",\"200\"]},{\"name\":\"fs3\",\"value\":[\"1\"]},{\"name\":\"fs4\",\"value\":[\"2\"]}]"

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode($all_opt),true)` check this one

Comment: it only go back to the first pattern